# Cant get return value from user defined functions in SAS

Tags: macros, sas, user-defined-functions

I have a function which calls a SAS macro that is responsible for making a call to an API and get your answer. This function is called from a step data, passing a parameter.

The whole process works properly, except I can not get the response value in datastep.

If I run the macro separately, I can write to the log the API response, so I understand should be able to return to my datastep.

Any ideas?

Here is the code

**Macro**

```
%macro acortador();
%put &url_larga;

data _null_;
 length url $ 2048;
 url = catt(
 'http:XXXXXX',urlencode(trimn(&url_larga)));  
 call symputx('REQUEST_URL', url);
 run;

 %put &REQUEST_URL;

/* API request */
filename out "XXXXXXXX.xml";

proc http 
    out=out         
    url= "%superq(REQUEST_URL)"
    method="get";
run;

/* response xml */
filename data 'XXXXXXX.xml';

data _null_;
    infile data lrecl = 32000 truncover scanover;
        input                       
            @"<status>" shorturl $255. @@;
        shorturl = substr(shorturl,1,index(shorturl,'</')-1);   
        call symputx('r', shorturl);
run;

 %put &r;

%mend acortador;
```

**Function**

```
proc fcmp outlib=work.funcs.test;
function acortador(url_larga $) $ 300;
 rc = run_macro('acortador', url_larga, r);
  return (r);
endsub;
quit;

options cmplib=work.funcs;
```

**Datastep**

```
data test;  
    set work.origin_table;
    r = acortador(some_parameter);  
run;
```

Comment: What is `run_macro`? Is that another function?

Comment: Do you needed to invoke the macro. [Support.sas](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/proc/65145/HTML/default/viewer.htm#n19ylmyrvhp7y6n1889zmwsv9nuh.htm)

Comment: Thanks, I haven't seen this call function before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is with the return variable **r** used in RUN_MACRO. You have not assigned a length to it, by default SAS is assuming it be a number and hence you might be getting a . (numeric missing). If you try and make you macro definition generate let say %let r=1; then you would get return value of 1 in your current code. But since we are looking at getting the modified response string. So to get character value, just add length for r before r first usage.

```
length r $ 32767;
rc = run_macro('acortador', url_larga, r);
```

I hope this helps.